# Convert string to Object C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Which object do I have to use to convert JSON string when I use

```
jsonstring = "{"message":"success","ID": "[83689707,83689708]"}"
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResponseMail>(jsonstring);
```

I tried this object but convert fails:

```
public class jsonResponseMail
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<int> ID { get; set; }
    }

  public class jsonResponseMail
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<string> ID { get; set; }
    }

   public class jsonResponseMail
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public int[] ID { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class jsonResponseMail
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string[] ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The "id" is not an array, its a string.

Comment: Use: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your string it should be

```
public class jsonResponseMail
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

If you are expecting a list then string would be

```
{"message":"success","ID": [83689707,83689708]}
```

and class would be

```
public class jsonResponseMail
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<int> ID { get; set; }
}
```

Also `jsonResponseMail` does nor adhere to class naming conventions. Use `JsonResponseMail` instead.

Comment: yeah, i did it, but the ID is a "complex" string  "[83689707,83689708]", i want to get two values "83689707" and 83689708 when i deserealize this string without clean a string ID.

Comment: In that case you need to create your own logic of converting `string` to `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your JSON string manually. Something like this:

```
var original = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponseMailOriginal>(json);
var ids = original.Id.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
var result = new JsonResponseMail()
{
    message = original.message,
    Ids = ids
};
```